# .net vb 9 richboxtext business

Tags: .net, vb.net, click, richtextbox

I am not so good at .net but I hope you will help me out. Thanks in advance.
Let assume below will be my richtextbox. This is what I have so far:

[U]Title name 1[/U]
Some text. Some more text.

[U]Title name 2[/U]
Some text. Some more text.

What I am willing to do now is:

1. Only when you mouse over on underlined text - mouse cursor
   changes to 'Hand'
2. Then you can click on it and messsage box appers with underlined
   text.

How do I do these two things? :|

Answer (score 0):

So essentially you're trying to Hyperlink the Underlined text in your RTB?  I've played with attempting to do this and haven't really found anything that works too well.  What I suggest is (if you do not require scroll bars) to place LinkLabels over each of the underlined titles and make those events point to where ever you need them to.  Alternatively, if you don't want the RTB's boundaries showing then just use a series of LinkLabels for titles and Labels for the text below them.

Not sure how current this is, but certainly worth a try:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=355994